# sed/awk copy line number x to line number y

Tags: awk, sed

Here is my file (temp.dat):

```
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
qrst
uvwx
yzzp
aprd
wsuo
zrnt
```

From this file, I would like to copy the (whole content) of line 2 to the line 9, meaning getting this new file:

```
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
qrst
uvwx
yzzp
aprd
efgh
zrnt
```

Here is my implementation

```
awk '{if (NR==2) s=$0;if (NR==9) print s;print NR" "$0}' temp.dat > new.dat:
```

Output

```
1       abcd
2       efgh
3       ijkl
4       mnop
5       qrst
6       uvwx
7       yzzp
8       aprd
efgh
9       wsuo
10       zrnt
```

I do not understand why these numbers appear. Can someone help me please with awk or sed.

Comment: how about `awk 'NR>=2 && NR<=9' inputfile`

Comment: The numbers are there because you include `NR` in your printing

Comment: Do you ONLY want to print a line from earlier in the file later (e.g. print line 2 instead of line 9) or do you sometimes want to print a line from later in the file earlier (e.g. print line 9 instead of line 2)? The latter requires a different solution to the former.

Answer (score 2):

With `sed` you could save line 2 in the hold buffer and substitute it in on line 9, e.g.

```
sed '2h; 9x' infile
```

Similarly with `awk`

```
awk 'NR==2 { s=$0 } NR==9 { $0=s } 1' infile
```

Output in both cases:

```
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
qrst
uvwx
yzzp
aprd
efgh
zrnt
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
awk '{if (NR==2) s=$0;if (NR==9) print s;print $0}' temp.dat
```

You can omit in your origin print statement `print NR" "$0` the numbers with the extra space `NR" "`.

Comment: @rogwar You are welcome. If this answer is right and you want to help the community finding right answers, please mark this answer as a right one.

Answer (score 0):

[The Standard Editor](https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html) has a command for this, `line-from t line-to`, e.g.:

```
echo '#\
9d
2t8
w outfile
q
#' | ed infile
```

After this `outfile` contains:

```
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
qrst
uvwx
yzzp
aprd
efgh
zrnt
```